concurrent async_write on the same strand
Here is an example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/chat-multi/websocket_session.cpp
You can see that they have some queue'ing logic in order to only have one async_write at a time. In particular, under on_send and on_write.
My question: Is this necessary if we know that the underlying executer is guaranteed to be serialized (via strand)?
From my understanding, this falls under case 2 of this answer, so I am curious why the queue serialization was necessary in the example.

Yes. "the underlying executer is guaranteed to be serialized (via strand)"  doesn't actually mean a lot.
Executors aren't serialized (they're just copied, they're data). What is serialized is the execution of handlers on a strand. In the linked example the send() operation does not originate from the strand. As such, you have to post sending to the strand.
Also, the queue is there because multiple threads can call send and even though the initiations would be serialized, the async-operations themselves would overlap if the former operation didn't complete before the second was initiated.
The requirement for that is documented on all composed write/read operations e.g. here:

This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other writes until this operation completes.

Or here:

The algorithm, known as a composed asynchronous operation, is implemented in terms of calls to the next layer's async_write_some function. The program must ensure that no other calls to write, write_some, async_write, or async_write_some are performed until this operation completes.

The Asio operations have similar requirements: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html

"the queue is there because multiple threads..". even with one thread, we would still have this problem, right? if there is multiple send operations that initiate an async_write each, and we're not guaranteed the prior async_write has finished.

True. I was somewhat vaguely thinking of logical threads. You're right, with a single thread you can have multiple intertwined sessions still, and they could trigger overlapping writes
